# How to correct errors associated with code completion on Eclipse with TFS (Team Explorer Everywhere) plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse (actually, IBM's AST for WebSphere - based on Eclipse 3.2.1) and the Team Explorer Everywhere plugin for TFS. After starting a new project and getting the code from TFS, I've noticed that attempting to update any Java code results in the following error message:

```
 "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project."
```

Searching the web resulted in a suggestion that the following be added to the .project file of the project:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

However, doing this results in my package declarations (within any classes) to be marked as follows:

```
The declared package "some.package.name" does not match the expected package "".
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from the required .class files.
```

Another suggestion is to change the build path of the application, such as by deleting and reestablishing the JRE system library. My experience has shown that this option is only available in the Properties menu if the "natures" are added to the .project file.

As a last resort I tried generating a new workspace and had the same results there.

Is there a specific "nature" for TFS that I need to add, or another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually importing?  Is it an existing Java project?  Is it an Eclipse project?  Does the folder you're importing contain the `.project` file, or is it in a subdirectory?  Or is there no `.project` file at all?

The error about package declarations being incorrect makes it sounds like you might have imported something deeper in the project hierarchy (ie, importing `$/Project/src/some/package/name` instead of `$/Project'.)  Is this possible?

Comment: There is a `.project` file (which is where I attempted adding the `nature` entries). This was set up as a Maven project initially. We first create the maven structure using `mvn archetype:generate` and then import the project into Eclipse via `Import->Existing Project`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to this problem - it is related to how I was importing the application from TFS.

Our application structure is setup as (for example):

app-name-app
    |
    app-name-ear
    app-name-war
    app-name-jar

So, just import the ear, war, jar, etc. as needed. Importing app-name-app was the source of the problem. For my project, I have an ear and a war - importing just these two items resulted in AST/Eclipse behaving correctly.